# Solr 4.0 Beta Tutorial

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

Hi I want to know the new features and advantages of Solr 4.0 Beta than its previous versions. Is there any documents or tutorials available? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/CHANGES.txt to see what changed between Solr versions.

Changes under 4.0.0 mean that these changes are not available in 4.0-BETA but will be available in the final release.